# Can I say "be sure you are adapted to the idea" when I'm asking for someone's agreement or support?

Tags: word-choice

I want to know more about the word `adapt`. Is it good to use it to connect people and things?

For example, is it ok to say: I adapt to playing basketball?

Comment: `Adapt` implies change of some kind.  Your example sentence `I adapted to playing basketball` could work if you mean that you worked on changing your body type or mental approach to defense to become a better basketball player.  The sentence in your title is a bit of a stretch.  I am not totally sure what you are trying to say, but something like _Be sure you are **comfortable with** the idea..._ may get you closer.

Comment: Are you *asking someone if* they agree or support the idea, or are you *telling someone they must* agree or support the idea?

Comment: @JeffreyKemp It's a bit mixed. It's like someone wants to join my team but I am asking him whether he can agree some conditions, if not, I won't accept him.

Comment: In that case you're not asking or telling, you are saying that IF they agree, they may join your team. If they don't agree, they cannot join.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Actually I am wondering what should I say to them to confirm that they agree my conditions (in this case is that they agree with my idea)

Comment: Just ask, "Do you agree with my conditions?"

Comment: Are [Do you find] my terms (or *Is my idea*) ***acceptable*** [to you]?

Comment: Or, "Here are my conditions. Can you work with them?"

Comment: I find it very stilted and would not know what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapted to the idea - No. 'Be sure you are comfortable with the idea' is what I think you are looking for. 'Make sure' is perhaps more natural.
@Jim's suggestion is good, if that's the way you meant it, as is @JefferyKemp's. 'Are you sure you are comfortable with this' is a likely expression, with 'are you on-board with this' being a bit more colloquial / American.
Adapt definitely doesn't work in this context, and is more useful in the context of getting used to cold/altitude/isolation etc, not *necessarily* physical things but certainly more environmental than attitudinal. Playing baseball, not really; you improve at that, you learn [to do] it, but you don't really adapt to it.

Answer (score 0):

you could say "be sure you *have adopted* the idea."

you can also say "i adopted basketball official rules" contrasting that before you played recklessly and now you have adapted to regulated play.

or "i adopted basketball as a hobby"

if on the basketball example you want to emphasize (biological) adaptation to basketball, you can say "i've evolved into a basketball player" or "i've developed a basketball body"